# Reading multi topics in Kafka Listner Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have two different topics to be read and post the processed data to a webservice. I have a condition, i have to read messages from topic1 completely and ensure if no messages are from topic1 I have to read messages from topic2 and process it. In case I start reading messages from topic2 and get messages from topic1, i have to pause processing messages from topic2 and read messages from topic1.

I somehow managed to do it using KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.
ListnerConfig code are

```
@Bean(kafkaListenerContainerTopic1Factory)
 public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerTopic1Factory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(60000L);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }


    @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerTopic2Factory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerTopic2Factory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

Listner code are

```
@KafkaListener(id = "first-listener", topics = "topic1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerTopic1Factory")
    public void receive(@Payload List<String> messages,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets)  {
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
            LOG.info("received first='{}' with partition-offset='{}'",
                    messages.get(i), partitions.get(i) + "-" + offsets.get(i));
        }
    }





@KafkaListener(id = "second-listener", topics = "topic2", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContaierTopic2Factory" , autoStartup="false" )
    public void receiveRel(@Payload List<String> messages,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
            LOG.info("received second='{}' with partition-offset='{}'",
                    messages.get(i), partitions.get(i) + "-" + offsets.get(i));
        }
    }

    @EventListener()
    public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        LOG.info("Inside event");
        this.registry.getListenerContainer("second-listener").start();
    }
```

I should also be able to manage these topics in when i have muliple instance of application running, for example when i deploy this code in OpenShift, i ahve to manage them within pods.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want to prioritise messages of topic1 over topic2. This is not directly possible with Kafka library. You will have to implement custom wrapper on top of Kafka to achieve the priorities. You can refer an example here : https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/priority-kafka-client